# Grouping same date JSON data together Using java

Tags: java, json

I have created one json Object Using java and it's values are given below

```
{
  "result":[
    {"ID":7252,"Age":52,"Date":"2015-11-25","DAY":"Wednesday","Gender":"M"},
    {"ID":7252,"Age":52,"Date":"2015-12-05","DAY":"Saturday","Gender":"M"},
    ....
  ],
  "status":"ok"
}
```

I need to group data as per date,required format is given below

```
{
  "result":[
    {"2015-11-25":[
      {"ID":7252,"Age":52,"Date":"2015-11-25","DAY":"Wednesday","Gender":"F"},
      {"ID":7252,"Age":52,"Date":"2015-11-25","DAY":"Wednesday","Gender":"M"}
    ]},
    {"2015-10-25":[
      {"ID":7252,"Age":52,"Date":"2015-10-25","DAY":"Tuesday","Gender":"F"},
      {"ID":7252,"Age":52,"Date":"2015-10-25","DAY":"Tuesday","Gender":"M"}
    ]},
  ],
  "status":"ok"
}
```

Basically i need group all same date data together inside JSON
with date as key 
How can i achieve this JSON format using java

Answer (score 4):

What kind of JSON mapper do you use? Jackson, GSON, ...?

And please provide some code. So we can see what you're doing.

---

If you created the JSON object using Java, you should have a Java Object structure, right?

Something like this:

```
class Data {
  int id;
  int age;
  LocalDate date;
  ...
}
```

And somewhere an Array / List of your data:

```
List<Data> result = new ArrayList<>();
result.add(data1);
result.add(data2);
result.add(data3);
```

Then you can use Java8 Stream API to group your data:

```
Map<LocalDate, Data> grouped = result
    .stream()
    .collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(Data::getDate)
    );
```

The result will be a `Map`. Your result should be a `List`.

So you should be able to simply iterate over the `Map` and insert it into a new `List`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON library such as *Josson* to do the transformation.

https://github.com/octomix/josson

```
Josson josson = Josson.fromJsonString(
    "{" +
    "  \"result\":[" +
    "    {\"ID\":7252,\"Age\":52,\"Date\":\"2015-11-25\",\"DAY\":\"Wednesday\",\"Gender\":\"M\"}," +
    "    {\"ID\":7252,\"Age\":52,\"Date\":\"2015-12-05\",\"DAY\":\"Saturday\",\"Gender\":\"M\"}," +
    "    {\"ID\":7252,\"Age\":52,\"Date\":\"2015-11-25\",\"DAY\":\"Wednesday\",\"Gender\":\"F\"}," +
    "    {\"ID\":7252,\"Age\":52,\"Date\":\"2015-12-05\",\"DAY\":\"Saturday\",\"Gender\":\"F\"}" +
    "  ]," +
    "  \"status\":\"ok\"" +
    "}");
JsonNode node = josson.getNode("field(result.group(Date).map(Date::elements))");
System.out.println(node.toPrettyString());
```

**Output**

```
{
  "result" : [ {
    "2015-11-25" : [ {
      "ID" : 7252,
      "Age" : 52,
      "Date" : "2015-11-25",
      "DAY" : "Wednesday",
      "Gender" : "M"
    }, {
      "ID" : 7252,
      "Age" : 52,
      "Date" : "2015-11-25",
      "DAY" : "Wednesday",
      "Gender" : "F"
    } ]
  }, {
    "2015-12-05" : [ {
      "ID" : 7252,
      "Age" : 52,
      "Date" : "2015-12-05",
      "DAY" : "Saturday",
      "Gender" : "M"
    }, {
      "ID" : 7252,
      "Age" : 52,
      "Date" : "2015-12-05",
      "DAY" : "Saturday",
      "Gender" : "F"
    } ]
  } ],
  "status" : "ok"
}
```